How to catch exceptions by std::condition_variable::wait_for()
For some reason, my project is always crashing when I call std::condition_variable::wait_for(). Unfortunately, this project's crash handler goes out of its way to be as unhelpful as possible, but it seems pretty clear from log messages that wait_for() is crashing, but my try-catch block isn't working, so I have no idea what the problem is.
The worker thread is supposed to do some work, then sleep for 60 seconds and work again. Obviously, not ad infinitum, so that's why we have the conditional_variable to wakeup the worker thread early and exit the loop. This is the code in the worker thread:
static void spawned(CmdHandler *pThis) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(pThis->m_mxQuit);
    while (!pThis->m_bQuit) {
        lk.unlock();
        pThis->worker.work();
        lk.lock();
        LOG_DEBUG << L"gonna give him wait_for() and I own the lock: " << (lk.owns_lock() ? L"true" : L"FALSE") << L"!";
        try {
            auto ret = pThis->m_cvQuit.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::seconds(60), [&] { return pThis->m_bQuit.load(); });
            LOG_DEBUG << L"and ret is (" << (ret ? L"true" : L"false") << L") and pThis->m_bQuit (" << (pThis->m_bQuit ? L"true" : L"false") << L")";
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) {
            LOG_DEBUG << L"ugh: " << toWide(e.what());
        }
        catch (...) {
            LOG_DEBUG << L"Unknown";
        }
    }
}

std::future<void> m_threadMeta;
std::condition_variable m_cvQuit;
std::atomic_bool m_bQuit;
std::mutex m_mxQuit;

The call to spawned() is very simple:
m_threadMeta = std::async(std::launch::async, spawned, this);

It doesn't lock m_mxQuit or affect m_cvQuit, and this (which is a CmdHandler) definitely lasts for the thread's duration--the dtor is not called.
I'd show you the main thread code which sets m_bQuit, but I guess there's no point, because it never gets called: debug log messages make that clear.
That first debug message before the try writes to the log, and it indicates that the thread owns the lock, but none of the other messages get through, so it's pretty clear that what_for() crashes, but I can't see anything wrong with call, and I'm not getting any log feedback about what's wrong.
I'm doing this in VS2015.
Edit:
As per recommendations, I've also tried this, but they made no difference--it still crashes on wait_for():
static void spawned(CmdHandler *pThis) {
    bool bQuit;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(pThis->m_mxQuit);
        bQuit = pThis->m_bQuit;
    }
    while (!bQuit) {
        pThis->worker.work();
        bQuit = pThis->waitForQuit();
    }
}

bool waitForQuit() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_mxQuit);      //wait_for() insists on unique_lock
    LOG_DEBUG << L"gonna give him wait_for() and I own the lock: " << (lk.owns_lock() ? L"true" : L"FALSE") << L"!";
    m_cvQuit.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::seconds(60), [&] { return m_bQuit.load(); });
    LOG_DEBUG << L"back and now quit is: " << (m_bQuit ? L"true" : L"FALSE") << L"!";
    return m_bQuit;
}


Check pThis is still valid and has not been deleted on another thread; or even by pThis->worker.work();

@RichardCritten I think the most reliable way to do that would be to show this line: std::async(std::launch::async, spawned, this);. It's the only one that calls spawned().

@Opux That doesn't tell anything about the lifetime of this/pThis. Is the thread launching std::async waiting to destroy this until after .wait() or .get() on the std::future returned by std::async?

Your example also lacks a declaration for m_bQuitPRT. There is only m_bQuit. The volatile on m_bQuit is suspicious, because it has no relevance to the synchronization you are showing. The synchronization is and can be achieved only via the m_mxQuit mutex.

(And this probably is not an exception if you say "crash" and catch doesn't see it. It is probably something like a segmentation fault or similar resulting from UB.)

The m_bQuitPRTs were a mistake. I've taken them out

This probably isn’t the problem, but volatile (as in volatile bool m_bQuit;) has nothing to do with thread synchronization. Use std::atomic<bool> instead.

@PeteBecker I tried that. When I used it as the Predicate in wait_for() there was a problem. Apparently you can't use std::atomic<> that way

@Opux your lambda should then return pThis->m_bQuit.load() ... because atomics are not copyable.

The problem is in the code that you are not showing, most likely in CmdHandler, and/or in the way you create your async operation. Also, calling lk.unlock(); lk.lock() manually is asking for troubles. You should create lk in a new scope, use it with cv.wait_for, and rely on RAII to unlock it. If you need to lock your mutex inside work, just use std::lock_guard, and also let RAII unlock it.

@AhmedAEK Ok, calling load() did allow me to make m_bQuit an atomic_bool, but even w/the refactoring I gave in the edit, it didn't fix the crash.

@pptaszni Ok, I refactored to your specifications, but I'm afraid it made no difference. I also gave the call which spawns spawned(). As you can see, there's no much to that call
